# SQL: Getting possible values for 'IN' operator from two different tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables with the following schema:

Table1 columns: ID MsgNum Msg
Table2 columns: ID MsgNum SystemId
Table3 columns: ID MsgNum IncidentNum

I want to get all items in Table 1 with MsgNum within a range of values selected from Table 2 and Table 3.

From Table2, the possible values for MsgNum is obtained using the following SQL:

```
SELECT Table2.MsgNum from Table2 WHERE SystemId = 'Sys-0001'
```

and from Table3,

```
SELECT Table3.MsgNum from Table3 WHERE IncidentNumber = 'Incident-0001'
```

Now, I will like to use a combination of MsgNum values obtained from the previous 2 SELECT statements to get the corresponding rows in Table1 as follows:

```
SELECT * from Table1 where MsgNum IN ( SELECT Table2.MsgNum from Table2 WHERE SystemId = 'Sys-0001'  OR  SELECT Table3.MsgNum from Table3 WHERE IncidentNumber = 'Incident-0001')
```

But this SQL fails using Interactive SQL.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If any one of this answers solved your problem you should really mark it as an answer as this helps the community find answers faster later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean UNION ?

```
SELECT * 
from Table1 
where MsgNum IN 
( 
SELECT Table2.MsgNum from Table2 WHERE SystemId = 'Sys-0001'  
UNION 
SELECT Table3.MsgNum from Table3 WHERE IncidentNumber = 'Incident-0001'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use EXISTS instead

```
SELECT * from Table1 t1 
where EXISTS ( SELECT t2.MsgNum from Table2 t2 
 WHERE t2.SystemId = 'Sys-0001' AND t2.MsgNum = t1.MsgNum)
OR  EXISTS (SELECT t3.MsgNum from Table3 t3 
 WHERE t3.IncidentNumber = 'Incident-0001' AND t3.MsgNum = t1.MsgNum)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.   However, this looks a lot more complex that the Union, especially considering that my question is simplified.  So I am inclined to use Union.

Comment: You should try _both._ Depending on your DB and the distribution of MsgNum, one might be significantly faster. (Probably the UNION version, but I have learned not to bet on SQL optimizer behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the UNION command to put two queries together

```
SELECT * from Table1 where MsgNum IN (
 SELECT Table2.MsgNum from Table2 WHERE SystemId = 'Sys-0001'
   UNION
   SELECT Table3.MsgNum from Table3 WHERE IncidentNumber = 'Incident-0001')
)
```

Comment: Hmmmm.  Union does the trick but I do not understand the concern posted by Martin.   Could you please elaborate.